# Uniform convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin\frac{x}{n}\sin 2nx}{x^2+4n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I have a task to research $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin\frac{x}{n}\sin 2nx}{x^2+4n}$ for uniform convergence on $ -\infty<x<+\infty $. I think, I should use Weierstrass M-test, but I can't find the sequence. So what sequence should I use or maybe another test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f_n(x)$ be given by

$$f_n(x)=\frac{\sin(x/n)\sin(2nx)}{x^2+4n}$$

Using the [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means), we assert that

$$|f_n(x)|\le \frac{|x|}{n(x^2+4n)}\le \frac{1}{4n^{3/2}}$$

> Inasmuch as $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4n^{3/2}}<\infty$, the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$ uniformly converges for $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and ***not only on compact subsets thereof***.

Comment: Good catch! (+1)

Comment: @olivieroloa Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. One may observe that
$$
\left|\frac{\sin\frac{x}{n}\sin 2nx}{x^2+4n}\right|\le\frac{\left|\sin\frac{x}{n}\right|}{4n}\le \frac{\frac{\left|x\right|}n}{4n}\le\frac{\left|A\right|}{4n^2},\quad x \in [-A,A] \,\,(A>0),
$$ by using [the Weierstrass M-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test), this gives the *uniform convergence* of the given series over each compact set of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Olivier, we need not restrict the uniform converge to compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.  In fact, we have UC on the reals. I've posted a solution to reveal this. ;-))

Comment: @Dr.MV Sure! Thanks ;)

Comment: @Gold Feniks Feel free to pick up Dr MV's answer! I just gave you a hint;)

Comment: You're welcome.